# Is there any easy way to export user input into a text file?

Tags: java, file, text, export

Preferably in the same class?

I tried this: http://mrbool.com/how-to-store-data-with-java/25483

but it was to hard to manipulate my data.

Are there any other easier ways?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.nextLine();
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("outputFile.txt");
p.println(s);
...
p.close();
```

Scanner can grab user command-line input and store it as a String, which can easily be sent to a file.

Comment: It says it cannot find symbol "PrintWriter"

Comment: import java.io.*;  (at the very beginning, before you write the class)

Comment: If you use the IDE Eclipse (eclipse.org), it should tell you how to fix that particular problem by the way.

Comment: what would go where the "..." is? more strings to print?

Comment: If you use Netbeans, it will flag `PrintWriter` with error; Alt-Enter shows "hints", first of which is to add import for `PrintWriter`. Just select it (it should already be selected) and hit Enter.

Comment: ... could be more strings if you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is anything like what you're after, but ...

```
package test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  static String endOfInputDelimiter = "/";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("outputFile.txt");
        while(scan.hasNext()){
          String s = scan.nextLine();
          if(s.equals(endOfInputDelimiter))
            break;
          p.println(s);
        }
      p.close();
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

It's pretty hokey; I especially don't like the "`if...break`", but maybe it's a start for you.